# Text spilling into adjecent cells in threeparttable despite specifying column width

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I am trying to make this table, but the text keeps spilling into the adjacent cells despite specifying the column width. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\sisetup{retain-zero-uncertainty=true}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{threeparttable}  
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} 
p{2.5cm} 
l
S[table-format=3.2(5)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
S[table-format=3.2(4)]
S[table-format=3.2(4)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Group} &
\textbf{Compound} & 
\textbf{Sample} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Met 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Met 2}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Dia 1}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Dia 2}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fal 1}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fal 2}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}*{Cholesterols/others} &
\multirow{2}*{{cyclopentanoperhydrophenanthrene}} &
Acrotab &
0.18(08) &
0.15(00) &
0.22(00) &
0.15(00) &
0.03(00) &
NA \\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
4.10(168) &
2.88(30) &
2.88(30) &
3.45(8) &
0.92(4) &
0.04(1) \\
\cline{2-9}
 &
\multirow{2}*{3-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl CoA} &
Acrotab &
0.21(37) &
0.36(2) &
0.53(21) &
NA &
NA &
NA\\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
7.12(256) &
4.74(37) &
7.92(48) &
5.67(32) &
0.66(57) &
NA\\
\cline{2-9}
 &
\multirow{2}*{indole-3- carboxylic acid} &
Acrotab &
17.13(894) &
15.56(123) &
19.21(195) &
16.58(31) &
1.50(06) &
NA\\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
402.67(17943) &
321.13(593) &
430.54(3571) &
333.67(3723) &
50.53(234) &
18.47(54)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

That produces an output that looks like this:

[image: Test_image]

This happens even though I have specified `p{2.5cm}` in the `\tabular{}` setup. It seems that the column width is getting adjusted, but the text isn't wrapping. I thought this was supposed to wrap the text as well. I haven't shown it here, but even when I add `\-` between the syllables, it doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- if you use `*` for the width of the multirows, they will adapt to the width of the text. To use the width of the column instead, use `=`
- if you have unusual words like `cyclopentanoperhydrophenanthrene`, you can help latex to find suitable breaking points by marking them with `\-` (I'm not a chemist, please check the ones I added in the code below, they might very well be wrong)
- even if the text breaks across lines, the two rows you allocated were too small to fit your looooooooooong words. I used a smaller font size and made the second column wider

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{tight-spacing=true}
\sisetup{retain-zero-uncertainty=true}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}  
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.3pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm} 
p{3.4cm} 
l
S[table-format=3.2(5)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
S[table-format=3.2(4)]
S[table-format=3.2(4)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
S[table-format=3.2(2)]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Group} &
\textbf{Compound} & 
\textbf{Sample} & 
{\textbf{Met 1}} & 
{\textbf{Met 2}} & 
{\textbf{Dia 1}} & 
{\textbf{Dia 2}} & 
{\textbf{Fal 1}} &
{\textbf{Fal 2}} \\
\midrule
\multirow{6}{=}{Choles\-terols/ others} &
\multirow{2}{=}{{cyclo\-pen\-tano\-per\-hydro\-phen\-anthrene}} &
Acrotab &
0.18(08) &
0.15(00) &
0.22(00) &
0.15(00) &
0.03(00) &
NA \\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
4.10(168) &
2.88(30) &
2.88(30) &
3.45(8) &
0.92(4) &
0.04(1) \\
\cline{2-9}
 &
\multirow{2}{=}{3-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl CoA} &
Acrotab &
0.21(37) &
0.36(2) &
0.53(21) &
NA &
NA &
NA\\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
7.12(256) &
4.74(37) &
7.92(48) &
5.67(32) &
0.66(57) &
NA\\
\cline{2-9}
 &
\multirow{2}{=}{indole-3-carboxylic acid} &
Acrotab &
17.13(894) &
15.56(123) &
19.21(195) &
16.58(31) &
1.50(06) &
NA\\
\cline{3-9}
 &
 &
Marotab &
402.67(17943) &
321.13(593) &
430.54(3571) &
333.67(3723) &
50.53(234) &
18.47(54)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'm not a chemist either, but I'd guess `\hyphenation{cyclo-pen-tano-per-hydro-phen-anthrene}`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Having `per` as a syllable makes much more sense

Comment: For check of hyphenation I use service on https://www.hyphenation24.com/?term=...

Comment: @Zarko I'm not sure if the site can cope with chemistry terms: it gives me "cy–clopen–tanop–er–hy–drophenan–threne" which does not look right...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, you may be right, I'm not chemist either, so in my answer I use your hyphenation pattern for this long word :-)

Comment: @Mico -- I'm no chemist either, but I pretty much agree with your segmentation, although I wish two levels were possible; I think the hyphen after "pen" is less desirable than the others.  In my TUGboat column for the issue now at the printer, I've asked the question "Is chemistry (for purposes of (La)TeX hyphenation) a language?" and I'm hoping for some answers and good arguments.  (In my opinion, it should be so considered.)

Comment: What is the point of using a float inside `landscape`? Or of specifying `!h`?

Comment: @cfr Indeed, this does not make a lot of sense. I removed the floating option.

Comment: But does it make sense to use a float inside `landscape` at all? Wouldn't `sidewaystable` be better, for example? I mean, you don't want the table to float out of the landscape ....

Comment: @cfr Sideways table would also work, but completely without a `table` it would not be centred on the page.

Answer (score 3):

- Your table doesn't contain any table notes, why you than use `threeparttable`?
- Another way to write your table is use `tabularray` package. With it  resulted table is to my opinion nicer
- Syntax for multirow cell `\SetCell[r=<num. of rows>]{<options>} cell contents` in `tabularray` is equivalent to syntax of `multirow{num. rows>}{=}{content of cell}` (as suggested in the @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer) with important difference that `<num. rows>` means number of rows and not number of lines in spanned rows as in `multirow` cells.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         tight-spacing=true,
         retain-zero-uncertainty=true}
\newcommand\NA{\SetCell{guard,c} NA}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 3 pt,
             colspec = {@{}  X[0.75,l] 
                             X[1.75,l]
                             l 
                             Q[c, si={table-format=3.2(5)}]
                             Q[c, si={table-format=3.2(2)}]
                        *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=3.2(4)}]}
                        *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=2.2(2)}]}
                        @{}},
             row{1}  = {guard, font=\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Group   & Compound  & Sample    & Met 1 & Met 2 & Dia 1 & Dia 2 & Fal 1 & Fal 2 \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{} Choles\-terols/ others
        & \SetCell[r=2]{}   cyclo\-pentan\-oper\-hydro\-phenan\-threne
                    & Acrotab   & 0.18(08)  & 0.15(00)  & 0.22(00)
                    & 0.15(00)  & 0.03(00)  & \NA       \\
    \midrule
        &           & Marotab   & 4.10(168) & 2.88(30)  & 2.88(30) 
                    & 3.45(8)   & 0.92(4)   & 0.04(1)   \\
    \midrule 
    & \SetCell[r=2]{}   3-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl CoA
                    & Acrotab   & 0.21(37)  & 0.36(2)   & 0.53(21) 
                    & \NA       & \NA       & \NA       \\
    \midrule
    &               & Marotab   & 7.12(256) & 4.74(37) & 7.92(48) 
                    & 5.67(32)  & 0.66(57)  & \NA       \\
    \midrule
    & \SetCell[r=2]{}  indole-3- carboxylic acid
                    & Acrotab   &17.13(894) &15.56(123) & 19.21(195) 
                    & 16.58(31) & 1.50(06)  & \NA       \\
    \midrule
    &               & Marotab       & 402.67(17943)     & 321.13(593)   & 430.54(3571) 
                    & 333.67(3723)  & 50.53(234)        & 18.47(54)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can observe that this table is due to used bigger font size (`\small`) as you use in your MWE (`\scriptsize`) is much better readable.